# Action to specific files while in os.walk loop

Tags: python, list, file, readfile, os.walk

I have 50 instances of two files that are in 50 separate folders within a directory. I am trying to read from and extract information from the two files within each folder and append the info from the two files to a list at the same time while in the folder that contains them both. (So they will be associated by being appended to the same same list index) I'm using os.walk and opening the file as soon as the file is recognized. (Or trying to). When I run it is seems like the files in question are never being opened, and definitely nothing is being appended to my lists. Could someone tell me if what I have here is completely ridiculous because it seems logical to me but its not working.

```
import os
import sys
#import itertools

def get_theList():

    #specify directory where jobs are located
    #can also set 'os.curdir' to rootDir to read from current
    rootDir = '/home/my.user.name/O1/injections/test'
```

No issues here; this is correct

```
    B_sig = []
    B_gl = []
    SNR_net = []
    a = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
        for folder in dirs:
            for file in folder:
                if file == 'evidence_stacked.dat':
                    print 'open'
                    a+=1
                    ev_file = open(file,"r")
                    ev_lin = ev_file.split()
                    B_gl.append(ev_lin[1])
                    B_sig.append(ev_lin[2])
                    print ev_lin[1]
                    ev_file.close()
                if file == 'snr.txt':
                    net_file = open(file,"r")
                    net_lines=net_file.readlines()
                    SNR_net.append(net_lines[2])
                    net_file.close()
    print 'len a'
    print a
```

This says 0 on output

```
    print 'B_sig'
    print B_sig
    print len(B_sig)
    print 'B_net'
    print B_gl
    print len(B_gl)
    print 'SNR_net'
    print SNR_net
    print len(SNR_net)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_theList()
```

Comment: You refer to `'rootDir'` when perhaps you mean `rootDir`. The former will look for a folder _named_ "rootDir", and _not_ the `rootDir` variable you've made.

Comment: Thanks that was one problem.

Answer (score 0):

From `help(os.walk)`:

> filenames is a list of the names of the non-directory files in dirpath.

You're checking to see if a list is equal to a string.

```
files == 'evidence_stacked.dat'
```

What you really want to do is one of the following:

```
for file in files:
    if file == 'evidence_stacked.dat':
        ...
```

Or...

```
if 'evidence_stacked.dat' in files:
    ...
```

Both will work, but the latter is a bit more efficient.

---

**In response to your edit:**

Instead of...

```
for file in folder:
    ...
```

use...

```
for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(rootdir, folder)):
    ...
```

Also, where you use `file` after that, replace it with

```
os.path.join(rootdir, folder, file)
```

or store that in a new variable (like, say, `file2`) and use that in place of `file`.

Comment: Thanks, that did help open the first file but it still wouldn't append anything. I changed what I have so it will go in the directories and not try to find files in the root but now it's not opening them again.

Comment: @spacedancechimp: I think you'll have to use either `os.walk` again (recursively, maybe) or `os.listdir` on `folder`.

Comment: thanks this is helping. I'm getting `'str' object has no attribute 'listdir'`

Comment: @spacedancechimp: Whoops, that was my fault. See my edit.